# Gridview Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am using Gridview and using Item Template text box. There are 5 text box and i am adding a new row dynamically on clicking on add row btn. in that row i have adding all text box which is empty. Now i want to validate that text box on btn click next.

now to do it?

I used required field validation its working for first time showing text box but when i am adding a new row text box its not causing the validation, I think there is some other way to give validation for dynamically added text box.

How could i validation my all dynamically added text box

Grid view which i am using..

```
            <Columns >

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="otherOthersTd">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblcnt" ForeColor="#136A96" Text='<%#Eval("Count") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Width="88px"></asp:TextBox>

                            </ItemTemplate>


                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Middle Name">

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MName") %>' 
                                     Width="88px"></asp:TextBox>

                            </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LName") %>' 
                                     Width="88px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Degree">

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDegree" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Degree") %>' 
                                    Width="50px"></asp:TextBox> 

                            </ItemTemplate>


                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' Width="88px"></asp:TextBox>

                            </ItemTemplate>


                    </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                     <ItemTemplate> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="Server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' Width="88px" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExpr" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid email id" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="a" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                         <asp:Label ID="revexp" runat="server"  > </asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Institution">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInstitution" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Institution") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>


     <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" ValidationGroup="a" CausesValidation="true" Text="Next" class="next btn" onclick="btnNext_Click"/>
```

```
                    <asp:TemplateField>  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblAuthor" runat="server" Text="Authorerror" Visible="false"  ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large">*</asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <HeaderStyle  Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#136A96" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

my code...

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        if (e.CommandName.Equals(""))
        {
            lstAuthors = (List<OtherAuthors>)Session["lstAuthors"];
            if (lstAuthors.Count == 0)
            {
                OtherAuthors obj0 = new OtherAuthors();
                obj0.Count = "Author 1:";                    
                lstAuthors.Add(obj0);
            }
            int index=GridView1.Rows.Count-1;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox Name = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
                TextBox MName = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtMName") as TextBox;
                TextBox LName = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLName") as TextBox;
                TextBox Degree = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtDegree") as TextBox;
                TextBox Title = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
                TextBox Email = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox;
                TextBox Institution = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtInstitution") as TextBox;

                if(Name!=null)
                {

                lstAuthors[i].Name = Name.Text;
                lstAuthors[i].MName = MName.Text;
                lstAuthors[i].LName = LName.Text;
                lstAuthors[i].Degree = Degree.Text;
                lstAuthors[i].Title = Title.Text;
                lstAuthors[i].Email = Email.Text;
                lstAuthors[i].Institution = Institution.Text;
                }
            }
            OtherAuthors obj1 = new OtherAuthors();
            obj1.Count = "Author "+(lstAuthors.Count+1).ToString()+":";
           obj1.Name="";
           lstAuthors.Add(obj1);

           GridView1.DataSource = lstAuthors;
           GridView1.DataBind();
           for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               if (GridView1.Rows.Count - 1 == i)
                   GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Visible = true;
               else
                   GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Visible = false;
           }
           Session["lstAuthors"] = lstAuthors;
        }
        MultipleModalitySelect1.hideChosebutton = true;

    }
```

private bool IsValied()
        {
            bool error = false;

```
            TextBox Name = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
            TextBox MName = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtMName") as TextBox;
            TextBox LName = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtLName") as TextBox;
            TextBox Degree = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtDegree") as TextBox;
            TextBox Title = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
            TextBox Email = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox;
            TextBox Institution = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtInstitution") as TextBox;
            Label lblAuthor = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblAuthor") as Label;

            if (Name.Text.Length == 0 || LName.Text.Length == 0 || Degree.Text.Length == 0 ||Title.Text.Length == 0 || Email.Text.Length == 0 || Institution.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                lblAuthor.Visible = true;
                error = true;

            }
            else
            {
                lblAuthor.Visible = false;
            }
```

}

Comment: @Ansari; Validation problem is when you added control at runtime ? Otherwise its working perfectly ? Please post your complete code, so that we can figure your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used the validation group's `ValidationGroup="a"` on your Next button, but you have not used that on the Required Field Validator. But you have used it in the Email validator.

You have to be consistent with the Validation control and whether to put validation on all controls and button controls for it to work.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" ValidationGroup="a" CausesValidation="true" Text="Next" class="next btn" onclick="btnNext_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start a new page and test with a much smaller case scenario and get that working first.  Then add more boxes.

If you still need help with that smaller page, post it for help - it will be easier for us to understand it.

Comment: You Should write this in comment instead answer.